# How to debug rules that are not being run?

Tags: 7, rules, debugging

I have few rules bound to the **Event**: **Completing the checkout process**

After completing the checkout process these rules should run - but they do not work...

I am using [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/Devel) module to debug the Rules and in the dblog there is nothing about these rules - There are only rules that are actually being run upon other events.

How can I debug this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/config/workflow/rules/settings

Enable all debugging and it should show in the log if the event is correct. It will go through each condition and say which passed and which failed.